# Using MAX text or more specific, smaller type

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, datatypes, varchar

Someone was reviewing my DDL code for creating tables and suggested, when they saw I saw using `VARCHAR(256)` fields for text I expect to be pretty small, like a first name or whatever, that I should *always* just use `VARCHAR(MAX)` and linked [Why use anything but varchar(max)](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2006/02/28/Why-use-anything-but-varchar_2800_max_2900_.aspx). I read it but it seemed dated, as it was focusing on 2005, and didn't seem to offer any real justification to allocate potentially up to 2 GB per row on all text fields.

From a performance, storage, etc. standpoint, how should one go about deciding whether to use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or a smaller more specific type for modern versions of SQL Server? (e.g., 2008, 2012, 2014)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Should I always use `(n)varchar(max)` for text columns?

**No.**

For SQL Server, the `max` data types should only be specified when there is no alternative. One should instead choose the correct base type (`varchar` or `nvarchar`) and specify an explicit maximum length that is appropriate to the data to be stored.

Physical storage is identical whether the column is typed as `varchar(n)` or `varchar(max)`, so that is not the concern.

The reasons to **not** choose `(n)varchar(max)` everywhere revolve around features, plan quality, and performance.

An exhaustive list is probably not practical, but among other things, `max` columns:

#### Features

- Require a separate constraint to enforce a maximum length
- Cannot be a key in an index (so no unique constraints either)
- May prevent online DDL (including index rebuilds and adding a new non-null column)
- Are generally not supported for 'newer' features e.g. columnstore
- See the product documentation for more specific features and limitations. The general pattern is that there are awkward limitations and restrictions around `max` data types. Not all limitations and side-effects are documented.

#### Performance

- Require special handling in the execution engine, to account for the potentially very large size. Typically, this involves using a less efficient code path, with a streaming interface
- May have similar unanticipated consequences for external code (and other SQL Server components like SSIS), which must also be *prepared* to handle data up to 2GB in size
- Are assumed to be 4000 bytes wide in memory grant calculations. This is likely to lead to excessive memory reservation, which limits concurrency, and pushes valuable index and data pages out of cache memory
- Disable several important performance optimizations
- May extend lock duration
- May prevent the optimizer choosing a (non-dynamic) seek plan
- Prevent filters being pushed into scans and seeks as a residual
- May increase tempdb pressure and contention (version dependant), since variables and parameters are also likely to be typed as `max` to match column definitions

---

In summary, there are so many subtle (and undesirable) side effects of unnecessarily using the `max` specifier that it makes no sense to do this. The minor 'convenience' of using a single declaration is no sort of compensation.

Evaluate each type in context, use the correct base type (`varchar` or `nvarchar`), and a sensible explicit length.

Further reading:

- [Performance comparison of varchar(max) vs. varchar(n)](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/) by Remus Rusanu
- [Read Committed and Large Objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/05/31/read-committed-and-large-objects/) by Craig Freedman
- [Capacity planning for tempdb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx)
- [Deletes that split pages and forwarded ghosts](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/08/deletes-that-split-pages-and-forwarded-ghosts.html) (me)

Answer (score 8):

This is going to read like a paranoid's answer, but there aren't *only* storage and performance considerations.

The database itself doesn't control its clients, and clients can't be assumed to always securely insert user input - even if a database is designed to be used only with a .net application that uses Entity Framework to encapsulate transactions and ensure parameterized queries are systematically used, you cannot *know* that it's always going to be the case.

I wouldn't know exactly how to do this, but by making all text fields `varchar(max)`, if a client has *Bobby Tables* issues and/or your stored procedures' parameters are also `varchar(max)`, then you're making it easier for an attacker to come up with a valid but cleverly evil parameter value that can do things that clients aren't supposed to be doing - whatever that is.

By limiting the length to what you *actually* need, you're not *shielding* yourself from these clever attacks (I'm not even sure what it's actually called, I just remember reading about it a while back), but you're not saying "go ahead, try to give me a 2GB script to run" either.

Comment: What it's called is probably "injection" ("SQL injection", more specifically).

Comment: @AndriyM yeah, for some reason I was thinking of *SQL truncation attacks* (MS seems to have taken down the link I had bookmarked), but that's basically exploiting `varchar(not-max)` parameters, so I kinda stuck a foot in my mouth here. But yeah SQL injection would be applicable here. Perhaps I should rephrase this answer a bit.